# Proving the inverse of $1/(1 + 2x)$ is $(1 - y)/2y$

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

Let $f(x) = 1/(1 + 2x)$. I want to show that $f^{-1}(y) = (1 - y)/2y$. Is it sufficient for me to show

$$f\left(\frac{1-y}{2y}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + 2(1 - y)/2y} = \frac{1}{1 + (1 - y)/y} = \frac{1}{y}= y?$$

Or, is there another way that this assertion needs to be proved?

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(y) = \frac{1-y}{2y}$. When you show $f(g(y)) = y$, what you know from there is precisely the following: $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. You don't know that $f$ or $g$ are bijective yet.

Now, you can also show that $g(f(x)) = x$ and from there it will follow: $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective.

Combined, you've shown $f\circ g = id$ and $g\circ f = id$, i.e. you've shown $g=f^{-1}$ by definition.

---

However, if you knew that $f$ is bijective (or even just injective) beforehand, and you showed $f(g(y)) = y$, then it would be enough to conclude that $f^{-1} = g$. This is because if $f$ is injective, there exists $h$ such that $h(f(x)) = x$. Now,

$$h = h\circ id = h\circ f\circ g = id\circ g = g\implies f\circ g = id\ \text{and}\ g\circ f = id.$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative firstly note that $f(x)$ is defined $\forall x\neq -\frac12$ and since

- $f(x)=\frac1{1+2x} \implies f'(x)=-\frac2{(1+2x)^2}<0$
- $f(x)>0$ for $x>-\frac12$
- $f(x)<0$ for $x<-\frac12$
- $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)=0$

we have that $f(x):\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1/2\}\to  \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is bijective and then invertible.

To find the inverse we need to solve

$$x=\frac{1}{1+2y}$$

and find $y=g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: If I just want to show that $(1 - y)/2y$ is the inverse though, is it enough for me to just plug it in and show that the result is $y$?

Comment: you need to show that $f \circ f^{-1}$ and $f^{-1} \circ f$ are both identity. You have done only one way @stackofhay42

Comment: @stackofhay42 As noticed you need to complete with the other direction or as an laternative prove directly that for any $y=f(x)$ we can find one and only one x such that $x=g(y)$.